# SystemVerilog Assertion which checks that a clock is provided when active_clk is high

Tags: assert, system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

In the design specification that I'm veryifying the DUT against there is a requirement that the word clock and bit clock are being generated when the active_clk signal is high.  I've little experience in using SVA, so was hoping that someone with a little more experience could point me in the correct direction, or better yet, provide a solution.

Comment: Are there three clocks in all? One main clock, one high frequency bit clock and one low frequency word clock? Or just two of them? What is the frequency relation between bit clock and word clock?

Comment: There are two clocks; bit clock and word clock.  When the active_clk signal is high, these clocks must be generated.  Both of the clocks are generated independently from each other, so I am looking for two seperate (but likely identical) assertions to check that both clocks are generated when active_clk = 1.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/frequency-checker-system-verilog-or-verilog) and [this](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/checking-clock-period-using-system-verilog-assertion] forum questions and [doulos](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/) tutorial can give some initial understanding.

Comment: I've looked through the sources you recommend before and cannot come up with an effective solution to my problem, hence the post here as a last ditch effort.

Comment: There must be a main clock which is ALWAYS ON clock, generated from top module. Using the period of that clock, you can generate a local_clk for assertion module (or directly take away main clock as input). Now, bit_clk is *anded* with main clock, is what you want to check. This must be at both the edges, since we have to check for `0` and `1` in gated clock. I have made a sample [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7rJ) for single clock checking, this may not be most optimized way, but it shall fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Have an always ON clock which you can use to predict rising/falling edges of other 2 clocks within some fixed/calculated duration. Something like below code:

```
 bit aon_clk;
 always #1 aon_clk = ~aon_clk;

 property clk_chk;
   @(aon_clk)
   // Within say 25 Always ON Clks, you should expect a rise/fall of bit_clk
   active_clk |=> ##[0:25] $rose(bit_clk) && active_clk ##[0:25] $fell(bit_clk) && active_clk;
 endproperty

 assert property (clk_chk) else $display($time," Clks not generated");
```